# Python|Keras: how to define a callback to interrupt/exit training per user's request

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, interrupt

Currently, I can "safely" interrupt Keras neural net training via:

1. [early stopping callback](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-interrupt-training-when-the-validation-loss-isnt-decreasing-anymore) (once accuracy improvements are small)
2. stopping the execution and restarting from the last [saved model](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model)

However, I'm looking for a way to have a more robust way to interrupt the training.

Is there a way to create a local dummy (flag) file and check its existence in a callback after each epoch ends? How can this be implemented? Are there another way to interrupt training on a single CPU/GPU architecture, running in PyCharm (Windows 10 x64, Python 3.6, Anaconda 3, Keras 2.1.2, TensorFlow 1.4, PyCharm)?

I suppose, I could start in debug mode of PyCharm and pause execution whenever needed, but debugger is slow and I'm not sure if the pause will propagate through Keras and to underlying TensorFlow.

Comment: Isn't there a manual code interrupt? It doesn't cause harm if the model is in the middle of training. (It may cause harm in the middle of compile, training initialization, etc.)

Comment: I'd like the training to interrupt, but for the code to continue execution. I.e. for Keras to give the control back to my code which would use whatever model has been learned so far to make predictions. Restarting the console is equivalent to manual code interrupt, I suppose, but it kills local variables and NN will lose current epoch and anything since the last saved model (saving at every epoch is inefficient).

Comment: Probably a manual stop does not clear the variables. I don't know Pycharm, but I use Jupyter Notebook and I never cared about creating an interrupt method. I manually stop the code and then call other routines.

Comment: Daniel, perhaps, I'm not understanding what you mean by "manual stop". The "pause" and "stop" in PyCharm are only available during the debugging mode. Could you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the `keras.callbacks.Callback` class to create your own callback with your own logic:

You can use code similar to the EarlyStoppingCallback

https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/callbacks.py#L429

you add a listener for the epoch end event.

```
def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
    if you_are_tired_of_training_condition:        
        self.stopped_epoch = epoch
        self.model.stop_training = True
```